# How to refactor parameters in if-else condition coming from a request laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-request, laravel-controller

I have this function in my controller that checks parameter requests and saves it into my table for tracking. However my `if condition` is quite too long because whenever a new request will be added I have to write individual `if condition` to each request.

**Here is my code:**

```
public function storeTracking(Request $request)
{
    $traffic = new TrafficTracking();

    if ($request->has('gclid')) { // check if request = gclid
        $traffic->traffic_type = 'gclid';
        $traffic->traffic_value = $request->gclid;
    }

    if ($request->has('token')) { // check if request = token
        $traffic->traffic_type = 'token';
        $traffic->traffic_value = $request->token;
    }

    if ($request->has('fbclid')) { // check if request = fbclid
        $traffic->traffic_type = 'fbclid';
        $traffic->traffic_value = $request->fbclid;
    }

    if ($request->has('cjevent')) { // check if request = cjevent
        $traffic->traffic_type = 'cjevent';
        $traffic->traffic_value = $request->cjevent;
    }

    $traffic->save();

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'success'
    ], 200);
}
```

Is there any shorter approach for this one for the `if condition`? Because the code will be long whenever a new request is added in my `storeTracking` function in the controller.

Comment: you can use the switch case if there multiple conditions or use Ternary operators

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh could you show us example? For future purposes so that others might have the same problem, they can replicate it.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this but you need to way to validate or in try catch you need to handle

this code can be like this

```php
foreach ($request->except('_token') as $key => $value) {
    $traffic = new TrafficTracking();
    $traffic->traffic_type = $key;
    $traffic->traffic_value = $value;
    $traffic->save();
    break; // if you want single time execution 
}
```

> **NOTE** i m not sure it is correct answer but it is an idea to solve this

Comment: Is this okay to use the `foreach` function and inside that function is only the `type` and `value` and the `new TrafficTracking()` and also `save()` is outside the foreach?

Comment: yes you can use but it will overwrite `$traffic->traffic_type` this that's why i put like that and i added `break` statement so it will loop single time

Answer (score 1):

**Using Ternary Operators**

```
(Condition) ? (Statement1) : (Statement2);
```

Condition: It is the expression to be evaluated which returns a boolean value.

> Statement 1: it is the statement to be executed if the condition
> results in a true state.
>
> Statement 2: It is the statement to be executed if the condition
> results in a false state.

**Using switch case**

```
switch (n) {
    case label1:
        code to be executed if n=label1;
        break;
    case label2:
        code to be executed if n=label2;
        break;
    case label3:
        code to be executed if n=label3;
        break;
    ...
    default:
        code to be executed if n is different from all labels;
}
```